# Indexed SharePoint list item not being shown in search results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

We have a list on SharePoint 2013 which contains servers IP adresses. For two items, their management IP adresses are the same, but server IP adresses are different. When we search this item on the list, SharePoint shows only one item, not the other.

What should I do to make the order item shown in the search results?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you need to make sure the missing item is crawled. You can check that via checking the item in Crawl Log.

Some item may be hidden in list search result. You can click "Include" to show these hidden items:
[image]